# Scrolling page script in asp.net mvc. Using @RenderBody() function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap + asp.net mvc by making portfolio website.

It is based on [bootstrap example.](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/)

On this example we see one page website. When we click e.g. "about" the site is using javascript and scrolling to about section. I understand that.

but... i want to try this 1 page website, spread on many Controllers (and views), use layout page with RenderBody() in it and keep the same funcionality like before(scrolling).

e.g my views:

- About/Index
- Portfolio/Index
- Contact/Index

and layoutPage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>



    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/font-awesome.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
<!-- NAVI -->
<div id="Navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-mm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navi</span> Menu<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to Site.com</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-select">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="/Portfolio/Index">Portfolio</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="/Home/About">About</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="">Contact</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="/Blog/Index">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Img/lawl.png" alt="">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <span class="name">mySite.com</span>
                    <hr/>
                    <span class="skills">Developer</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<div class="container">

    @RenderBody()

</div>
        <footer class="footer text-center">
            <div class="footer-upp">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="footer-col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <h3>CONTACT</h3>
                            tel: 000-000-000 <br />
                            email: example@gmail.com <br />
                            City
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer-col col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                            <h3>MEET ME</h3>
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="btn btn-socialmedia btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" class="btn btn-socialmedia btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://github.com/" class="btn btn-socialmedia btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="mailto:example@gmail.com" class="btn btn btn-socialmedia btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-down">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p>Copyright &copy;</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>


        <script src="~/Scripts/Site.js"></script>
```

There is anyway to make this?

Comment: So you mean to say that you want different Controller and view for each section?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers Yes. Different controller and view for each section. It is possible?

Comment: No. It's not possible.